# Export to PostgreSQL in QGIS 3 with permissions

Tags: qgis, postgresql, export

Is it possible to use the Export to PostgreSQL tool ([tool details here)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#qgisimportintopostgis) in QGIS 3 but to also set permissions for the table you are exporting into without having to run that in a separate console of database management software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PostgreSQL execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#postgresql-execute-sql) afterwards:

Allows a SQL database query to be performed on a PostgreSQL database connected to QGIS. The algorithm won’t create a new layer: it is designed to run queries on the layer itself.